# Forwarding port from one vps to another

Tags: networking, ip, routing

I made a VPN server (Shadowsocks, Openvpn, Wiregaurd, etc) on vps1.
I want to connect vps2 that redirects me on vps1. if its possible I want to forward all ports from vps2 to vps1.

Client -> vps2 -> vps1 (VPN)

and I need to redirect fast as possible.

Comment: I'm not at my PC hence the comment rather then answer. This is very possible. You can use iptables PREROUTING and NAT rules to intercept packets, rewrite and forward th on.  You will also need to turn ip_forwarding on if you have not already.  I'd suggest against forwarding ALL ports as that would mean you cant remote in to VPS1.

Comment: @davidgo i want to do this with wiregaurd vpn.. but its not working.

Comment: iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 5600 -j DNAT --to-destination 22.22.22.22:5600 | 

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 22.22.22.22 --dport 5600 -j SNAT --to-source 11.11.11.11

Comment: Did you manage to solve that?

Answer (score 1):

I did what you are trying to do in a couple of different ways.  The easier way is with rules like the following (which were for 2 ports, but you can adjust as required) -

The required commands on VPS2 were:

```
 iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 60.234.77.235
 iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j MASQUERADE
```

The above works and requires no changes on VPS1 but has the disadvantage of presenting all traffic as coming from VPS2 on VPS1 (ie VPS1 could not see the real source address in the IP packets)

You also need to turn net.ip4.ip_forward=1 on (in /etc/sysctl.conf and reload it).   My configuration also has net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter=1 and
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=1 but I don't think these are needed for the iptables only solution.

I rectified this by getting rid of the second IPTABLES rule and implementing policy based routing across a Wireguard VPN, so that if a connection had a destination IP of the wireguard interface it was routed back out the wireguard tunnel, while traffic directly to the machine did not go through the tunnel.  Setting up policy routing is a lot harder.

**As the rules you have added in to your comment are similar to the rules I used, the next step is to break out tcpdump on each of your boxes to see what traffic you are seeing coming in and out the interfaces on each box to narrow down where the problem is.**   One distinct possibility is that your VPS2 is not allowing forwarding of packets.  You may be able to solve this with

```
 iptables -I FORWARD -j ACCEPT
```

(or some tighter variant thereof).  You might also want to add an INPUT rule like the above temporarily just to rule that possibility out.

Comment: i tested this method with netcat.. i get Ncat: TIMEOUT.

Comment: and i track the traffic and i can see the vps2 forwarding but in vps1 nothing happens. i disabled firewall with ufw disable but same.

Comment: What does TCPDUMP tell you?   And are you actually running a tcp service on port 5600?

Comment: give me the TCPDUMP command them i show you.. i tried tcpdump -X -s0 port 5600. i dont know its ok or not.

Comment: The commands I used originally did not work well with the new AWS VM.  I have updated the rules to make use of masquerading to track return packets.